# jQuery each to assign an id with index

Tags: jquery, each

I have 32 images, and I was hoping that the following snippet would assign to each img tag an id starting from 1 to 32, but it assigns 32 to all of the ids. Where am i doing wrong?

```
var img = $('img');
img.each(function(item){
    img.attr('id', item);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `img` in each callback function

```
    var img = $('img');
    img.each(function(item){
        $(this).attr('id', item);
    });
```

Note: **Index starts with 0**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/3W5F9/)

Comment: Hi, why $(this) and not img? Sorry but I would like to understand better. Thank you

Comment: @Alex, `img` refers to the group, where as `$(this)` refers to individual item that is being referenced in the each bloack

Comment: @Alex,  the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var img = $('img');

img.each(function(ind,item){
    $(item).attr('id', ind);
});
```